# Sum each field in stream of objects

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I want to create instance of object MyObject, each field of which will be sum of values of that field from

I create an object

```
       public class MyObject{
           int value;
           double length;
           float temperature;

           MyObject(int value, double length, float temperature){
               this.value = value;
               this.length = length
               this.temperature = temperature
           }
        }
```

Then I construct list of objects:

```
    List<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<MyObject>{{
          add(new MyObject(1, 1d, 1.0f));
          add(new MyObject(2, 2d, 2.0f));
          add(new MyObject(3, 3d, 3.0f));
    }}
```

I want create object (`new MyObject(6, 6d, 6f)`)

It is easy to sum one field per stream:

```
Integer totalValue = myObjects.parallelStream().mapToInt(myObject -> myObject.getValue()).sum(); //returns 6;
```

or

```
Double totalLength = myObjects.parallelStream().mapToDouble(MyObject::getLength).sum(); //returns 6d
```

and then construct object `new MyObject(totalValue, totalLength, totalTemperature);`

But can I sum all fields in one stream?
I want stream to return

```
new MyObject(6, 6d, 6.0f)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The other solutions are valid, but they both incur unnecessary overhead; one by copying `MyObject` multiple times, the other by streaming the collection multiple times. If `MyObject` is mutable, the ideal solution would be a [mutable reduction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#MutableReduction) using `collect()`:

```
// This is used as both the accumulator and combiner,
// since MyObject is both the element type and result type
BiConsumer<MyObject, MyObject> reducer = (o1, o2) -> {
    o1.setValue(o1.getValue() + o2.getValue());
    o1.setLength(o1.getLength() + o2.getLength());
    o1.setTemperature(o1.getTemperature() + o2.getTemperature());
}
MyObject totals = list.stream()
        .collect(() -> new MyObject(0, 0d, 0f), reducer, reducer);
```

This solution only creates a single additional `MyObject` instance, and only iterates the list once.

Answer (score 2):

It is a direct application for `reduce` method:

```
Stream.of(new MyObject(1, 1d, 1.0f), new MyObject(2, 2d, 2.0f), new MyObject(3, 3d, 3.0f)).
                reduce((a, b) -> new MyObject(a.value + b.value, a.length + b.length, a.temperature + b.temperature))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like below

```
MyObject me = new MyObject(
    list.stream().mapToInt(MyObject::getValue).sum(),
    list.stream().mapToDouble(MyObject::getLength).sum(),
    (float)list.stream().mapToDouble(MyObject::getTemperature).sum());
```

This will do what you need. You can also use Stream.reduce to do the same thing.

Comment: This avoids creation of intermediate `MyObject` instances comparing to version with `reduce`.